# How do I update a React Element in 'componentDidUpdate'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying the render several react elements that rely on having the x and y coordinates of other react elements. I know that I have to update the elements in the 'componentDidUpdate' method since I cannot get the values until the component is rendered.

Current behavior has nothing being updated. renderNew contains the react elements that I want to render, but it is not updating as nothing is displaying.

I am not storing the values in state, I do not think that I needed to.

Here is where I am setting state and other variables

```js
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            priceDataData: jsonOrders.order.map(order => order.total),
            heightData: '',
            xElements: '',
            yElements: '',
            dotsWeWant: ''
        };
        this.dimensionsX = [];
        this.dimensionsY = [];
        this.renderNew = [];
        this.dotRef = [];
    }
```

Here is my componentDidUpdate method

```js
    componentDidUpdate = () => {

        const nodeRefs = this.dotRef;
        this.dimensionsX = this.connectTheDotsX(nodeRefs);
        this.dimensionsY = this.connectTheDotsY(nodeRefs);
        this.renderNew = this.renderNewLines(this.dimensionsX, 
        this.dimensionsY, this.state.priceDataData, this.state.dotsWeWant);

    }

    }
```

Snippet of my JSX with the variable that is not updating. It will be empty upon first rendering, and needs to be updated.

```
    <div className="graph_space">
       <div className="dot_container">
           {this.state.dotsWeWant}
       </div>
       <div className="test_stuff">
            {this.renderNew}
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The issue you're seeing is a timing thing. `componentDidUpdate` fires after `render` runs. So changes to a local property on your class (`renderNew` for instance) wont propagate to render because they aren't tied to your components lifecycle. Either move that to state, or you could call `this.forceUpdate()`. (id prefer moving to state). Be careful though, only update / re-render in a conditional check or you'll get to an infinite loop of updating and `componentDidUpdate` calls

Comment: Is there a way to safely run setState in 'componentDidUpdate'? It usually gives an infinite loop if I try to run setState in that.

Comment: Yes, you conditionally call it. Hard to explain the conditional without knowing the data. Usually its something like `if (!prevProps.something && this.props.something || prevProps.something !== this.props.something) { this.setState({...}) }`

Comment: What is the datatype of renderNew? What is `this.renderNewLines` doing / calculating?

Comment: `priceDataData: jsonOrders.order.map(order => order.total)` Is it right? What does it mean? I can't find `jsonOrders` in your codes. Is it in props?

Comment: `this.renderNewLines` is taking the x and y of the `dotsWeWant` elements that I am getting in `componentDidMount` the x and y coordinates should be changing then between rendering and the component updating?

Comment: @Antonio `priceDataData` is poorly named meta data that i am getting from a static json file, but I am performing actions with it before rendering.